# Let connections go through a server to a router in packet tracer

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

This may be a simple question but one that I have not been able to get a solid answer on as of yet. Is there a way in packet tracer that I can let packets go through a server that has two NICs? [image]

This is a simple diagram of what I'm looking for except I want that PC to be able to ping that router and have the router "route" everything in the network. I can clarify if needed.

Comment: There is not a lot of configuration for such devices. Packet Tracer is a simple tool to lhelp you learn CCNA-level networking, and it doesn't support advanced features.

Comment: @FinderFake Please clarify and expand.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to enable IP packet forwarding on the packet tracer server.  If you're not using the server-like features (eg http server), consider replacing it with a router called "Server-PT", then it will route though look funny on your diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco Packet tracer is CCNA Level Simulation software. Therefore it does not support advanced features. If you want to do advanced level configuration, you have to use GNS3. It will support virtualization and many advanced features such as packet capturing.

In addition to that you can use windows server environment or hyper v environment. You can add multiple network cards and routing facilities. Windows server provide virtual routing facilities. Even in linux also support these features in virtualization environment. (This is only to understand how routing is work. Not for Cisco)